# Select a File and Then send it as an Attachment Using Nodemailer! Nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, email, attachment, nodemailer

How can I attach the file which i have selected using input type file?

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn grey">
          <span>File</span>
          <input name="myImage" type="file" multiple="multiple"> 
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>      
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

this is the backend code

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: '****@gmail.com',
    to: '*****@gmail.com',
    subject: 'test',
    text: 'test',
    attachments: [{        
         // how to get the path of the selected file
    }]
  };
```

How can i get the path to include in the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

The attachment params is the filepath, so I think you have to write your uploaded file into the disk before attaching it into your mail. You can use nodejs fs module to do that.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
...
fs.writeFile('/your/path/to/your/fs', fileContent)
    .then(res => {
        const mailOptions = {
            from: '****@gmail.com',
            to: '*****@gmail.com',
            subject: 'test',
            text: 'test',
            attachments: ['/path/to/your/fs']
        };

        // I suppose sendMail return a Promise here !
        return sendMail(mailOptions)
    }).then(_ => fs.unlink('path/to/your/fs'))
    // fs.unlink is here to delete the file because it is useless now
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to extract files array from the request object and then pass this file array to the nodemailer as attachments

```
    var files = req.files;
    const mailOptions = {
            from: '****@gmail.com',
            to: '*****@gmail.com',
            subject: 'test',
            text: 'test',
            attachments: files
        };
```